# setting value to property of nested control that already have value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a CustomControl, let's say Grid with Button, which I can't modify directly. That nested button have Content property set to "Hello world". CustomControl don't expose this button to outer code. So, how can I set this property in my main window?
I tried to set style

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="Bye" />
</Style>
```

It works perfectly if button's property not set, sadly, that is not my case.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Property` in your `CustomControl` which gives back and sets the content of your button.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the user Control first

CustomControl = Page.FindControl("CustomControl name") as CustomControl;

and then try out getting the other control using the same way as above.

Note: I am not 100% sure that this will work. I answered because we use the same logic at some other. So this might help you out.

Comment: Well, this works for UserControl, but when I'm trying to find button in CustomControl, method return null. Maybe this is because button defined in style. Is there any way to find control in style?

Comment: Please use Quick Watch to know your Custom Control properties and attributes.
Use it wisely I am sure you will get that under Controls of your UserControl

Comment: One request if the answer id helpful, please do mark it as accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a Dependency property in your control to do this. [Here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/dependencyproperties.html) is a tutorial.

Comment: I can't modify control, since it's not mine and sits in external library